# sql sum case group by

Tags: sql

i have a problem. i need total value a group. my table is

example :

```
a       b              c
x      1.2.300         30
y      1.2.500         50
r      1.3.600         30
e      1.6.400         10
```

...

example 1.2.xxx london member 1.3.xxxx Manchester member. i want to group mamber in the same city and calculate total value c. but how?

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you have a reference table for your city that we can use in the `GROUP BY` expression?

Comment: @Kurkix, Check working fiddle in my answer. hope it helps!

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU, I SOLVED MY PROBLEM. THANK YOU FOR ALL

Comment: @Kurkix Accept an aswer so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that maybe

```
select city, 
       sum(c) as c 
from (
    select case when b like '1.2.%' then 'London'
                when b like '1.3.%' then 'Manchester'
           end as city, 
           c
    from my table
) group by city
```

Comment: What if you have an huge list of city?

Comment: you have to create a rule somehow on how to group them. Maybe if you take only the first 2 number ? is it enough ?

Comment: Yes you almost got it, have a look at my answer :)

Comment: basically, it is the author to decide which one is best for him. Maybe he has a reference table somewhere he can use to make the aggregation

Comment: You are right the author will decide which answer fit his needs the best :)

Comment: 1.2.% okay but 1.2.32% = london's brexley, 1.2.33% london's blendon etc.

Comment: i try calculate london's areas total value

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU, I SOLVED MY PROBLEM. THANK YOU FOR ALL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select SUBSTRING(T.b,1,3) as cityNumber, SUM(T.c) AS Total
From table T
Group by SUBSTRING(T.b,1,3)
```

**Working fiddle is** [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9276a2/2/0)

Comment: This does not works `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: SUBSTRING(T.b,1,3) is contained in group by. So using it in  select should not give error.

Comment: I tried in a simple SQL Fiddle and i still have the error :/

Comment: @LudovicFeltz I have added working fiddle. Please check.

Comment: You are right it works in MySQL my bad. The author did not specify which dbms he used and i though it was Oracle :) Sorry

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU, I SOLVED MY PROBLEM. THANK YOU FOR ALL

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle this should works:

```
SELECT cityId, SUM(c) as cSum
FROM(
    SELECT SUBSTR(b, 0, 3) AS cityId, c
    FROM myTable
) GROUP BY cityId
```

**Edit:**
As suggested by Steven you can find the last dot index with the INSTR function as following: `INSTR(b, '.', -1)`

So the query become:

```
SELECT cityId, SUM(c) as cSum
FROM(
    SELECT SUBSTR(b, 0, INSTR(b, '.', -1)) AS cityId, c
    FROM myTable
) GROUP BY cityId
```

Comment: It is a little more complicated but you can find the last index of the last dot as the second number of the `SUBSTR` function. I edited my answer.

Comment: it is not working either apparently, cause others codes need chars after 2nd dot

Comment: @StevenBENET Yeah i saw his comment but the author is not active enough... We should know the schema of the city's reference table too...

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU, I SOLVED MY PROBLEM. THANK YOU FOR ALL

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** Eliminate the last one and consider the rest of string in `GROUP BY` it will resolve your problem and helpful to consider codes more than specific numbers.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(b, SUBSTRING_INDEX(b, '.', -1), '') cityNumber,
    SUM(c) total
FROM testTable
GROUP BY REPLACE(b, SUBSTRING_INDEX(b, '.', -1), '')
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU, I SOLVED MY PROBLEM. THANK YOU FOR ALL